# Prolog: Check predicate against every item in the list

Tags: recursion, prolog

Basically, I want to be able to check to see if at least one value in a list satisfies some predicate.

What I have so far:

```
need(x,y).
check_list(X,[H|T]) :- 
   need(H,X).
```

And so this works fine so long as I only have one value in the list. I'm not sure how to make it check the other values. When I try and use recursion I eventually find an element that satisfies the second predicate but it then goes back up the stack which will eventually cause it to be false.How can I make it 'break' essentially?

Comment: You already have some proposed answers, but I'm not sure they answer what you really want. Can you give some concrete examples of queries you would like to succeed or fail? Do you really want a fact `need(X, Y)` to express that the list should contain a `Y`, and after that an `X`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give concrete code for certain reasons. Basically, I want to check the predicate need against every item in the list and if it's true at least one time then my original predicate would be true. I can kind of do this, but after I do find it it'll go back up the stack trace and fail one of those predicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backtracking you are seeing during recursion is Prolog attempting to find more ways for the predicate to succeed. This is a fundamental Prolog behavior and is what makes it useful. It seeks to find all of the solutions.

In your case, you only want to confirm one solution to the problem of, *An element in the list that meets a specific criterion*. For this, you could use a cut:

```
check_list(X, [H|_]) :-
    need(X, H), !.    % Don't backtrack after success
check_list(X, [_|T]) :-
    check_list(X, T).
```

Or you could use `once/1` which is specifically designed to handle cases where you only want a single solution:

```
check_list(X, [H|_]) :-
    need(X, H).
check_list(X, [_|T]) :-
    check_list(X, T).

check_list_once(X, L) :- once(check_list(X, L)).
```

Comment: You're first snippet was really helpful! Can you explain why you need the cut? I didn't have to use it. Also, unlike typical languages like C or Python, prolog will always go back up and check a prior predicate, right? So even if the first predicate was false at first, it'll go back and check when possible to see if that has changed?

Comment: @Notsoturingcomplete the cut in Prolog prevents backtracking. If it back tracks, it will try to figure nd more solutions. It will succeed for as many matches as it can find then finally fail to find more. Thus, after finding zero or more solutions, it ultimately comes back false, which is the scenario you said in your question that you wanted to avoid. With the cut after a success, there is no more checking, so there is no failure to find more solutions.

Comment: Ah okay, I guess I just need to make some better test cases to test that

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do.
I want to check is numbers are odd.

```
is_even(X) :-
   X mod 2 =:= 0.

check_list(L, CL) :-
    include(is_even, L, CL).
```

with result

```
?- check_list([1,2,3,4,5], L).
L = [2, 4].

?- check_list([1,3,5], L).
L = [].
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple recursion:

```
need(x,y).
check_list(X,[H|T]) :- 
   ( need(H,X) -> true; 
     check_list(X,T) ).
```

You can see in the examples below that this definition is deterministic:

```
?- check_list(y,[1,2,3]).
false.

?- check_list(y,[x,2,3]).
true.

?- check_list(y,[1,2,x]).
true.

?- check_list(Y,[1,2,x]).
Y = y.

?- check_list(Y,[1,2,3]).
false.

?- check_list(Y,[1,x,3]).
Y = y.

?- check_list(Y,[1,X,3]).
Y = y,
X = x.

?- check_list(Y,[1,2,3]), Y = x.
false.

?- check_list(Y,[1,2,3]), Y = y.
false.

?- check_list(Y,[1,2,3]).
false.

?- check_list(Y,[1,2,x]), Y = y.
Y = y.
```

Though if you want your queries to have uninstantiated variables e.g `check_list(Y,[1,2,x]).` and you add another fact `need(x,z).` Then:

```
?- check_list(Y,[1,2,x]).
Y = y.
```

Returns only one result and not Y = z. You could use **`if_/3`** from library **reif** if you want a better definition of `check_list/3`.

Answer (score 0):

Another neat option: use `member` to generate the solutions to pass to `once`, so you don't even need the explicit recursion.

```
need(x,y).
check_list(X,L) :- 
   once((member(H, L), need(H, X))).
```

Note the double parentheses. The inner ones groups the conjunction so the `,` isn't interpreted as a separator between arguments to `once`.